# How do I pass argv values from PowerShell to a Python Script?

Tags: python, powershell, arguments, argv

I would like to call a script in PowerShell so that the script can be called from any directory on the computer. I am using environment variables to call the script from a library directory. However, the script requires a argument in the call eg. script.py argv[1].

It looks to me as though the arguments are not being passed from the PowerShell command line when calling the python script.
As an example I believe the following is occurring:
I run the script as below

> script.py argv[1]
> This is passed by PowerShell to python.exe as:
> python script.py
> i.e. no arguments forwarded to the python execution

This script is run on a file and the argument passed is the file name to be processed. This operation is carried out on a number of files in different locations and

I have looked online for a similar issue without luck. The last attempt is to ask here.
I created a brief script to call out the arguments that have been passed.

```
print('Argument = ', sys.argv[0])
print('All = ', sys.argv)
```

No matter what I've tried the sys.argv list is always a single item argv[0] which contains the path for the script.py file.

I'm not fully familiar with the PowerShell commands but have tested the following:

1. & script.py $argv1
2. & script.py $argv1 = argument1

Comment: `python test.py foo bar=baz` is not giving you `['test.py', 'foo', 'bar=baz']`?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a ps1 script that is passed parameters and you seek to pass them on to a python script called by the ps1 script?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback  I found 'a' solution. %* was missing from the end of the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command